# ubuntu setting wallpaper in terminal

Tags: ubuntu, settings

how to setting wallpaper in terminal on Ubuntu 16.04.
I have tried many times in this command, it won't work:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/jintain/Pictures/WallPapers/images/2017_03_29.jpg
```

file followed my picture path, which I compeletely sure it is exist.
But this command just don't work at all, I am so confused, did I am wrong???? But I got this command in Ubuntu Forum they told this should be work. Any idea???? I am starting doubt my life.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `set` instead of `get`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/jintain/Pictures/WallPapers/images/2017_03_29.jpg
```

Comment: Oh, that's my bad this is exactly right way, thks very much!